# When user install Application, don't want application create it's icon on home screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Developers I am working on an AR application for android device. and i am using the tool "Unity Game Engine" the problem is that I don't want that when user install the android app from playstore it will not create shortcut icon on home screen.

Comment: it is not something you can choose. It is the user's launcher alpplication who decides if it will create your app's shortcut, or not.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is independent of the app. It comes from Play store itself. Open your play store, click on the hamburger menu icon on the top left, scroll down to setting and there you'll find an option saying Add icon to Home Screen for new apps. By default, it is checked and that's why all the icons of new apps are added to your home screen. Just uncheck it and you are good to go.

> Play Store -> Settings -> Uncheck Add icon to Home screen

Comment: Sir I think you missed my question I am not talking about doing it manually, instead it how to do it in code because thousands of people will use it after downloading from playstore so how is it possible tell them instruction.

Comment: Or is there any setting in android play console so we can do it at the time of Uploading on playstore

Comment: I don't think you can do that because it depends on the user's preferences.

Comment: As far I have read and searched, you can't do that individually for any app. Everything is in the hands of the user.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have also tried too much but didn't get any solution, is it possible to access playstore setting by code so I can disable this from my application?

Comment: No, play store doesn't give you the authority to change user preferences.

Comment: If you think my answer was of some use to you, kindly accept it. Thanks!